How are apps Like WhatsApp releasing builds with dark mode icons when only Xcode 16 Beta 5 is available?
On iOS 18 (Xcode 16), Apple has introduced app icon asset variants for dark mode and tinted mode. However, currently, only Xcode 16 beta 5 is available, which is not suitable for App Store releases. Recently, I noticed that apps like WhatsApp have released builds with support for dark mode app icons. How is this possible? Am I missing something?

You don't actually need Xcode 16 to update the Contents.json in the Assets folder.
What they did was to edit the AppIcon asset in Xcode 16 (or with any text editor), and the JSON happened to work when published for a app compiled in Xcode 15. I just verified this myself in the simulator (Xcode 15 build, targeting iOS 18 simulator)
Example of Contents.json with appearance specified:
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "filename" : "AppIcon.png",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "platform" : "ios",
      "size" : "1024x1024"
    },
    {
      "appearances" : [
        {
          "appearance" : "luminosity",
          "value" : "dark"
        }
      ],
      "filename" : "AppIcon-dark.png",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "platform" : "ios",
      "size" : "1024x1024"
    },
    {
      "appearances" : [
        {
          "appearance" : "luminosity",
          "value" : "tinted"
        }
      ],
      "filename" : "AppIcon-tinted.png",
      "idiom" : "universal",
      "platform" : "ios",
      "size" : "1024x1024"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "author" : "xcode",
    "version" : 1
  }
}


I have tried this, but iOS 17 doesn't consider this as valid app icon JSON. As a result, I am getting blank icons on iOS 17/18 while using Xcode 15. However, on Xcode 16 beta, the icons are properly rendered. @Claus Jørgensen

@Adarsh it works fine here, so you must have a bug in your images

@Adarsh mind you, Xcode 15 will use the images in some alphabetic order, so depending on what you called them it might use the wrong image, it's pretty obvious when you open the Assets file in Xcode 15

@Adarsh If you rename AppIcon.png to AppIcon-.png it will sort correctly and work on both Xcode 15 and 16.

@monchote can you elaborate on what the correct alphabetic sorting should be for it to work?

@epologee I explored this further and I couldn't make it work as Xcode 15 strips out the "unused" assets from the final product. I did manage however to make iOS 18 automatically generate the dark asset for me by changing the background of my app's icon to a lighter colour. I suspect this is what we are seeing for some of the popular apps that the author of the question mentioned.

Yeah, this worked in some earlier betas, but appears to have stopped working now. But the GA is probably a week or so out, so not a long time to worry about it.

If you remove all shadows and make the background a solid color, it'll work. No need to touch the .json file.

@BadrBujbara Letting Apple control the style/colours in dark mode isn't acceptable if you have a brand identity to uphold. It might work for SmoothieApp™, but it's not a good solution for big brands.

@Claus, I agree. My answer was good for tinted mode. I'm not sure how Dunkin', Subway, and Burger King have dark and light icons. Modifying the .json and adding dark and light icons didn't work.
